# Update JdbcTemplate by jdbcTemplate.update(List)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring Batch. How can I update all records in single database call?

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends Users> users) throws Exception {

    String updateQuery = "update users set ddp_created_fl=? where email=?";

    for(Users user:users) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(updateQuery, 1, user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `batchUpdate` to update all records in single database call.

```
public void write(List<Users> users) throws Exception {
    String updateQuery = "update users set ddp_created_fl=? where email=?";

    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(updateQuery,
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) 
                        throws SQLException {
                        ps.setLong(1, 1);
                        ps.setString(2, users.get(i).getEmail());
                    }

                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return users.size();
                    }

                });
}
```

Comment: `ps.setString(2, user.getEmail());` not compiling, how you taking getEmail from user

Comment: write method have List of users, whether you are iterating ? how you taking user.getXX

Comment: You dont need to iterate. Pls check the update answer.

Comment: with this code can I get better performance then what i was asked?

Comment: batchUpdate will be faster than update as you connect to database only once instead of n times for n records.